# Adding up JavaScript statements

Tags: javascript, html

I create a Random Fact generator, so when you press a button, a random fact appears. But something I can't figure out how to do is say how many facts I have. I want to say "There are # facts available" right under the button and for the number to update if I add more facts. Here's what I have for the generator.

```
<br />
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("<br>")

function onClick() {
function generateRandomFact(first, last) {
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (last - first + 1)) + first;
}

randomfactno = generateRandomFact(1, 15)

if (randomfactno == 1) {
alert("Dragonflies can't walk, despite having legs.");
}
else if (randomfactno == 2) {
alert("The chewing sounds from Bugs Bunny were made by chewing real carrots.");
}
else if (randomfactno == 3) {
alert("Yelling for 8 and a half years creates enough energy to heat 1 coffee cup.");
}
else if (randomfactno == 4) {
alert("Sign language speakers can speak in their sleep using sign language.");
}
else if (randomfactno == 5) {
alert("4 bits = 1 nibble.");
}
else if (randomfactno == 6) {
alert("German chocolate cake was made by an American.");
}
else if (randomfactno == 7) {
alert("Silver is predicted to run out by 2020, due to industrial use.");
}
else if (randomfactno == 8) {
alert("The first Youtube video was of Jawed Karim talking about elephants.");
}
else if (randomfactno == 9) {
alert("The Golden Gate Bridge's color is International Orange.");
}
else if (randomfactno == 10) {
alert("August 26th is International Dog Day.");
}
else if (randomfactno == 11) {
alert("A cat named  Meow weighed 39.6 pounds (18.0 kilograms), making him the heaviest cat in the world at the time, but not the heaviest on record.");
}
else if (randomfactno == 12) {
alert("Jean-Paul Sartre, awarded the 1964 Nobel Prize in Literature, declined the prize because he had consistently declined all official honours.");
}
else if (randomfactno == 13) {
alert("Presidents on other US Currency: William McKinley $500 bill, Grover Cleveland $1,000 bill, James Madison $5,000 bill, and Salmon P. Chase $10,000 bill.");
}
else if (randomfactno == 14) {
alert("The aurora at the south pole is called the aurora australis.");
}
else if (randomfactno == 15) {
alert("The jalapeno was the first pepper to travel into space.");
}
else {
alert("Javascript Error.");;
}
}
</script>
<div class="button">
<button onclick="onClick()">Generate Random Fact!</button>
</div>
</center>
```

Also, does anyone know a way to make this better. This generator repeats the same facts a lot even though there are 15 facts in it.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Put the facts in an array, and do `array.length` to get the number of facts, at  the same time, making your code a lot more DRY

```
var facts = [
    "Dragonflies can't walk, despite having legs.",
    "The chewing sounds from Bugs Bunny were made by chewing real carrots.",
    "Yelling for 8 and a half years creates enough energy to heat 1 coffee cup.",
    ...
]

var numberOfFacts = facts.length;

function onClick() {
    function generateRandomFact(first, last) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (last - first + 1)) + first;
    }

    var randomfactno = generateRandomFact(0, 14);

    alert( facts[randomfactno] );
}
```

If you don't want them to repeat, you can pop them off as you go

```
    var randomfactno = generateRandomFact(0, 14);

    alert( facts[randomfactno] );

    facts = facts.splice(randomfactno, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

It really can be made a hell of a lot smaller. I dislike using document.write because it overwrites the DOM, but you are already using it, so I figured for illustrative purposes it'd be fine.

```
var facts = [ 
  "Dragonflies can't walk, despite having legs.",
  "The chewing sounds from Bugs Bunny were made by chewing real carrots.",
  "Yelling for 8 and a half years creates enough energy to heat 1 coffee cup.",
  "Sign language speakers can speak in their sleep using sign language.",
  "4 bits = 1 nibble.",
  "German chocolate cake was made by an American.",
  "Silver is predicted to run out by 2020, due to industrial use.",
  "The first Youtube video was of Jawed Karim talking about elephants.",
  "The Golden Gate Bridge's color is International Orange.",
  "August 26th is International Dog Day.",
  "A cat named  Meow weighed 39.6 pounds (18.0 kilograms), making him the heaviest cat in the world at the time, but not the heaviest on record.",
  "Jean-Paul Sartre, awarded the 1964 Nobel Prize in Literature, declined the prize because he had consistently declined all official honours.",
  "Presidents on other US Currency: William McKinley $500 bill, Grover Cleveland $1,000 bill, James Madison $5,000 bill, and Salmon P. Chase $10,000 bill.",
  "The aurora at the south pole is called the aurora australis.",
  "The jalapeno was the first pepper to travel into space."
];

document.write("There are " + facts.length + " facts.");

function onClick() {
  alert(facts[Math.floor(Math.random() * (0, facts.length-1)) + 0]);
}
```